# selenium webdriver chromedriver path exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using linux64, I just want control chrome using selenium webdriver, For that I have downloaded and placed the the cromedriver in `"/usr/bin"` and changed the permissions `"a+x"`.

Now I am trying to run example results the path exception(`ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path`).

```
 File "test1.py", line 16, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 68, in start        
and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
    Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.                 
    Please download from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list and 
read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver'
```

After some research I just modified the sample code and I am still getting the same exception.

```
chromedriver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

How to resolve the exception?

Comment: What if you place chrome executeable into the home dir? Does it work?

Comment: no its also not working

Comment: Can you actually start the executeable from command-line?

Comment: running executable throws invalid encoding file

Comment: That's interesting. So, the problem is not in selenium - it's in an executeable itself.

Comment: oh thank you very much its 32 bit linux

Answer (score 0):

chances are this is a problem with driver you downloaded. you are most likely running a 32 bit driver on a 64 bit platform.